# Conflict with bluecove library

Tags: java, bluetooth, sunspot

I have a big problem according to the bluecove library which I am trying to use in an ANT project.

My project is a platform which receive messages from different agents, such as TCP agents, SunSpot agents (which use UDP), and now I'm trying to set bluetooth agents.

For this purpose is required the bluecove library, but result in conflict with javax.microedition.io used for example in the UDP classes that I'm implementing.

I guess that it's a library conflict, I have tried to put the bluecove-2.1.1 jar into the jdk1.6_xx/jre/lib/ext but this throws an exception in the UDP classes:

```
Error checking for shared basestation: javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: radiogram
javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: udp
javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: udp
  at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openImpl(MicroeditionConnector.java:185)
  at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.open(MicroeditionConnector.java:162)
  at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:83)
  at org.sunspotworld.SunSpotListener.run(SunSpotListener.java:48)
```

However if I remove from the content of bluecove2.1.1 jar the folder javax/microedition the error thrown is completely different:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   javax/microedition/io/Connection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/microedition/io/Connection
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.intel.bluetooth.Utils.class$(Utils.java:44)
at com.intel.bluetooth.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:44)
at javax.bluetooth.UUID.<init>(UUID.java:224)
at org.sunspotworld.BTListener.<clinit>(BTListener.java:28)
at org.sunspotworld.SunSpotHostApplication.run(SunSpotHostApplication.java:67)
at org.sunspotworld.SunSpotHostApplication.main(SunSpotHostApplication.java:342)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.microedition.io.Connection
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.microedition.io.Connection
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 8 more
... 8 more
```

I have read some solution involving xbootclasspath/a but I have no any idea what is that o how I can manage it...

Edit: I have used Xboothclasspath/a and /p to add the bluecove jar route, and the only thing I got was the chance to remove the jar import from my NetBeans project. Still not working. =(

Thank you very much in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you decided this error is caused by a conflict between the two libs as i don't see any mention to this in the error.

The second error (after removing the lib) simply states that it can't find the required classes (which is logical since you removed them :) ).

I'd suggest you check that the firewall is not blocking you.

Comment: I decided just because if I remove the UDP class, which use the javax.microedition.io, and I just use the bluetooth library it works, and viceversa. So I came to the conclusion that it's an error between these two libraries.

Comment: If you mentioned it in your question then i missed it :).

Comment: And switching off the firewall didn't succeed U_U and I'm getting mad with this issue since I need it for my work and I'm stack on this point.